# Jquery Remove Element After Deletion From Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a function that deletes images from my gallery. On the PHP side it works. With Jquery/Ajax it also works. But when I modified my jquery to remove the element when the image gets deleted(remove the element client side) it no longer works(when I say no longer works it is giving me the error function built into the code:

This code works:

```
function deleteImage(file_name)
{
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Image?")
    if(r == true)
    {
        $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: '/images/gallery/deleteImage.php',
          data: {'delete_file' :  file_name },
          success: function (response) {
             ohSnap("Image has been deleted.", "green");
          },
          error: function () {
             ohSnap("An error has occured.", "red");
          }
        });
    }
}
```

But this one doesn't

```
function deleteImage(file_name)
{
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Image?")
    if(r == true)
    {
        $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: '/images/gallery/deleteImage.php',
          data: {'delete_file' :  file_name },
          success: function (response) {
             $('#' + file_name).remove();
             ohSnap("Image has been deleted.", "green");
          },
          error: function () {
             ohSnap("An error has occured.", "red");
          }
        });
    }
}
```

Any idea why adding the remove function is causing an error? In console it is not telling me why, so I'm lost.

UPDATE:

Here is an example of one of the elements:

```
<div class="thumbImage" id="happy_anime_s2-1433126427.png">
<a href="images/gallery/happy_anime_s2-1433126427.png" data-featherlight="image">
<img src="images/gallery/happy_anime_s2-1433126427.png" width="200px" alt="" />
</a>
<span class="deleteImage">
<input type="hidden" value="happy_anime_s2-1433126427.png" name="delete_file" id="delete_file" />
<input type="button" value="Delete image" onclick="deleteImage('happy_anime_s2-1433126427.png');"/>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably meant method not methid ?

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that actually and updated it on my server with the same results. I'm going to update my question.

Comment: What exactly is the error that is generated? Is there an element that has an ID of `file_name` or is that only the name of the file on the server?

Comment: I updated my code to include an example of the html output from the server for one element. file_name comes from the actual file name using basename(); I also have that set to the id of the elements to try to simply this.

Comment: is there any errors in your browser console

Comment: None at all which I find odd. It's just the built in error which only started occurring when i added the remove function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `.` in the id, which creates a class selector. Looks at the selector `#happy_anime_s2-1433126427.png`, it looks for an element with id `happy_anime_s2-1433126427` and has a class `png`.

You need to escape the `.` using `\\.` like

```
$('#' + file_name.replace('.', '\\.')).remove();
```

[selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \.

Comment: Thanks so much! Your a life saver! I can work with some PHP, but anything javascript related kills me. Again thank you!